# The sum of two non-units of a ring $R$ is a non-unit implies that the Jacobson radical is maximal.

Tags: noncommutative-algebra

My problem is: If the sum of to non-units in a ring $R$ is non-unit, then the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ is maximal. I need help please. I have no idea how to start. 
I thought that if the set of all non-units is an ideal of $R$, then it turns to be the unique maximal left ideal of $R$ and so it is $J(R)$.

Comment: Can you show that this implies the set of non-units is an ideal?